# Where can I config my LSP server in AstroNvim?

Tags: neovim, lsp, astronvim

I have browsed [AstroNvim](https://astronvim.com) config extensively and even ran a grep seach for my LSP server's name but could not find mention of it. Yet I need to change the setup of this server :(. How can I do it?

The server is PyLsp, it is well installed and I want to config the linter rules.

I am on Ubuntu.

Here an example from [neovim/nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#pylsp)

````
require'lspconfig'.pylsp.setup{
  settings = {
    pylsp = {
      plugins = {
        pycodestyle = {
          ignore = {'W391'},
          maxLineLength = 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: you are barely providing any information here. What LSP Server are you using? Have you installed it? What exaclty are you trying to *change*?

Comment: I improved it but I think it was understandable

Comment: Thanks @samuel, could you tell is for which language it is? Could you tell us which configuration settings you want to change and what is the expected effect such that we can test the solution?

Comment: OK I've just done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come right by editing `~/.config/nvim/lua/user/lsp/config/pylsp.lua`

```lua
return {
  settings = {
    pylsp = {
      plugins = {
        pycodestyle = {
          ignore = {'W391'},
          maxLineLength = 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Much like the nvim-lspconfig example configuration you listed, but instead of `require`-ing it, returning the object directly.

Answer (score 1):

There are some documentation in [AstroNvim](https://docs.astronvim.com/recipes/advanced_lsp/) about advanced configuration of LSP servers.

e.g: If you want to disable formatting on save you could add a `~/.config/nvim/lua/user/init.vim` with the following content:

```lua
return {
  lsp = {
    formatting = {
      format_on_save = false, -- enable or disable automatic formatting on save
    },
  },
}
```

Remark: you'll have to create the `~/.config/lua/user` folder and the `~/.config/lua/user/init.vim` file that are not present by default.